# Hensel lifting of roots of a biquadratic polynomial

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials

Let $5$ divide $p-1$. Therefore, we have $$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=(x-\alpha)(x-{\alpha}^2)(x-\alpha^3)(x-\alpha^4)=f_1f_2f_3f_4$$ over $F_p,$ where $\alpha$ is an element of order $5$ in ${F_p}^\times.$ We can easily prove that $\left\langle x-\alpha^i\right\rangle$ and $\left\langle x-\alpha^j\right\rangle$ are co-prime in $F_p[x]$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq 4.$

Hensel lemma implies \begin{align} 
1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4&=g_1g_2g_3g_4
\end{align}
in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}[x]$ where $g_i's$ are co-prime and $\bar{g}_i=f_i.$ Here $\bar{g}_i$ means $g_i$ modulo $p$.

My question is that can we write $g_i=(x-\beta_i)$ for some $\beta_i \in {\mathbb{Z}}_{p^n}?$, i.e. can a simple root $\alpha_i$ be extended to $\beta_i$ such that $\bar{\beta}_i=\alpha_i$ ? If yes, then how to prove it?

Comment: You can use Hensel's lemma, already mentioned in your title.  What do you understand "Hensel's lemma" to mean?  I am not sure why you are doubting we can write $g_i = x - \beta_i$ when you know the $g_i$'s exist.

Comment: @KConrad From Hensel lemma, we can lift a pairwise co-prime factorization of a polynomial over $F_p$, to a pairwise co-prime factorization over ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p^n}$ such that the resultant factorization is reduced to the previous one under modulo $p.$ 

There is another interpretation that roots can be lifted to higher modulo prime-powers, but are congruent when reduced to lower primes, from which they are lifted.

In this case, we have to lift simple roots modulo p. I am confused because ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p^n}[x]$ is not UFD. How to justify this factorization in terms of simple liftings?

Comment: The distinct roots mod $p$ each lift to a unique root in the $p$-adic integers.  In $\mathbf Z_p[x]$, which is a UFD, the polynomial is a product of four monic linear factors. Now reduce *that* mod $p^n$.

Comment: @KConrad It is clear to me that simple roots will lift to unique roots in higher powers, but will the polynomial $$1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$$ have only these four roots (which are lifted from the base roots)? If yes, then its done. If not, then isn't the factorization contain more simple roots? and why can't these $g_i's$ be quadratic polynomials? (in non-UFD, we can have a situation like this) No? 

Kindly provide me some reference so that I can clear these concepts.

Comment: @KConrad If the extension of monic linear factors will be monic quadratic then following the degree sum argument on both sides, we can contradict. 

Is it the right reasoning that there will be exactly four monic linear factors in the extension also?

Comment: There is no need for any argument by contradiction. If a monic polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$ with degree $4$ has $4$ roots $r_i$ in $\mathbf Z$ then the polynomial is $\prod_{i=1}^4 (x-r_i)$. The same reasoning holds in $\mathbf Z_p[x]$.

Comment: @KConrad Yes. I get your point in ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p}[x].$ But it is not true for ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p^n}[x]$ in general. Therefore, if we start by monic coprime simple factors in  ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p}[x],$  then we can get the same kind of factorization over ${\mathbb{Z}}_{p^n}$ also.  Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know why you say it is not true mod $p^n$.  When $A$ is *any* commutative ring and $f(x) \in A[x]$ satisfies $f(a) = 0$ for some $a \in A$, we can write $f(x) = (x-a)q(x)$ where $\deg q = \deg f - 1$. If also $f(b) = 0$ and $b-a$ is a unit in $A$, then $0 = f(b) = (b-a)q(b)$, so $q(b) = 0$, so $q(x) = (x-b)r(x)$.  Then $f(x) = (x-a)(x-b)r(x)$. You can keep repeating this as long as you have roots in $A$ whose differences are units in $A$. When $A = \mathbf Z/(p^n)$ where $a$ and $b$ are roots with $a\not\equiv b\bmod p$, $a-b \bmod p^n$ is a unit.

Comment: You seem to be using just one version of Hensel's lemma, involving a coprime polynomial factorization.  There are many related results called Hensel's lemma, with no one result necessarily implying all the rest.  Look up a version of Hensel's lemma specifically about lifting roots of polynomials, not about coprime polynomial factorizations.

Comment: @KConrad Thank you so much. Now I completely understood that division kind of factorization also occurs over any commutative ring (as long as leading coefficient of the divisor $x-\beta_i$ is 1), with quotient reduced by one degree. 

Actually I need pairwise coprime in the next step of my work, to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem. Therefore, my though was stuck on that version. But, it is interesting to understand this way also. Firstly, lift the simple roots to unique roots using lemma and then divide by each monic term to get a factorization.